# Forgot how to handle click from action in model

Tags: angular, typescript

I created model for list of my buttons:

```
export class MenuElement {
  id?: string
  name: string
  tooltip: string
  icon: string
  action: void
}
```

And created simple menu:

```
constructor() {
    this.menu = [
      {
        id: '0',
        name: '',
        tooltip: 'Open in Mark',
        icon: 'launch',
        action: this.test()
      }
    ]
  }
```

I forgot after pause in angular how to link action in html, this way doesn't work:

```
<div *ngFor='let item of menu'>
    <div class="button" [title]="item.tooltip" (click)="item.action">
      <mat-icon>
        {{item.icon}}
      </mat-icon>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Test function just console logging Done.
Somebody can remind me how to do it? I can't find solution in web

Comment: Why did you create MenuElement class but don't create an instance of it? The second thing is why do you attach to action property `this.test` which points out always on component class, so you could call this method directly in template `(click)="test()"` it would be the same but cleaner. But if you want to execute action in class context - keep in mind than you have to bind 'this' manually or use arrow functions .

Answer (score 3):

In your model object `menu` you refer to the result of your action method, but it should be the method itself

Change this accordingly:

```
constructor() {
    this.menu = [
      {
        id: '0',
        name: '',
        tooltip: 'Open in Mark',
        icon: 'launch',
        action: this.test
      }
    ]
  }
```

In your template (Thanks to @Miri Gold):

```
<div class="button" [title]="item.tooltip" (click)="item.action()">
```

And in your model:

```
action: () => void
```

Comment: I also think the html code needs to be changed: (click)="item.action()"

Comment: and here is a live example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rcnzmx

Comment: And in model need to change action: void to action: () => void